# Silverstripe 3 - UploadField - stop upload popup appearing when enter is pressed in textfield

Tags: silverstripe

I have page/form in the SS 3 CMS that has an uploadfield on it - when I hit enter on other fields the popup to attach a file automatically shows, how can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: What version of the CMS are you using? What browser? If this happens on a base install the best place to raise this might be on Github as a bug: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework

Comment: As per the title I'm using SS 3.0 - and Chrome on Mac

Comment: I've logged a bug for this on Github: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3181

Comment: Oh right thanks I'm extremely new to SS and I'm working on someone else's codebase so I've got no experience setting up a blank slate - so thanks again